# Dynamically load Google Maps Markers with gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

How do I load only markers that are inside the map bounds with [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)? And of course load new ones after pan and/or zoom.

Directly related to that, how can I get the current boundaries and zoomlevel of the map?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how I did it, I only replace the markers after the user finishes panning or zooming, if you require different behavior then use a different event listener:

In your view (index.html.erb):

```
<%= gmaps({ "map_options" => { "zoom" => 15, 
                               "auto_adjust" => false, 
                               "detect_location" => true, 
                               "center_on_user" => true }}, false, true) %>
```

At the bottom of your view add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function gmaps4rails_callback() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.map, 'idle', function () {
        var bounds = Gmaps4Rails.map.getBounds();
        drawItems(bounds);
    });
}

</script>
```

In application.js (using jQuery):

```
function drawItems(theBounds) {
    var url = '/venues.json/?sw_y=' + theBounds.getSouthWest().lng() + 
                           '&sw_x=' + theBounds.getSouthWest().lat() + 
                           '&ne_y=' + theBounds.getNorthEast().lng() +
                           '&ne_x=' + theBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    $.get(url, function(newItemData) {
        Gmaps4Rails.replace_markers(newItemData);
    });
}
```

venues_controller#index:

```
def index
    # Only pull venues within the visible bounds of the map
    if (params[:sw_y] && params[:sw_x] && params[:ne_y] && params[:ne_x])
        bounds = [ [params[:sw_x].to_f, params[:sw_y].to_f], 
                 [params[:ne_x].to_f, params[:ne_y].to_f] ]
        @venues_within_bounds = Venue.within_bounds(bounds)
    else
        @venues_within_bounds = Venue.all
    end   

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { 
            @data = @venues_within_bounds.collect {|v| {
                     :longitude => v.longitude, 
                     :latitude => v.latitude, 
                     :picture => v.marker_picture, 
                     :title => v.marker_title 
            }
            render :json => @data
        }
    end
end
```

Venue.rb model (using mongodb and mongoid):

```
def self.within_bounds(bounds)
    self.where(:location.within => {"$box" => bounds })
end
```

Comment: This is a really great example. Just a quick note I believe the name space with the current version of gmaps4rails is Gmaps.map.map so...  google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.map, 'idle', function() {
      //do something
    });

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you really provide much feedback for the gem :)

Here is how I use it:

- to load only the useful markers, I filter them using [geokit-rails3](https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3) and the following scope: `Location.in_bounds([@south_west_point, @north_east_point], :origin => @somewhere)`
- when zoom or span, I only rely on the clustering which fasten the process
- to configure, map center and original zoom, see [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Map-configuration)
- you should code yourself the method to get the current boundaries, consider pulling :)