# AJAX updating based on filterrific filtering for Gmaps4Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a nice google maps view of all the restaurant listings on a page. I'm using the filterrific gem to sort/search without page reload, but gmaps4rails doesn't know it needs to update all the markers for the filtered results.

Right now I just have the same code I use for my static page maps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(17);
});
```

However this obviously only updates markers on initial page load (which doesn't actually grab anything, presumably because my listings are loaded in as a partial being handled by filterrific after gmaps4rails has initialized. Here is how the partial is drawn:

```
<%= render(
  partial: 'restaurants/list',
  locals: { restaurants: @restaurants }
) %>
```

I don't really know where to start when it comes to implementing AJAX (I think that's the term for it?) support. The threads I found upon searching didn't go into enough detail for me to understand what I should do (I'm very much a newb).

Thanks for any help you can offer, and if you need any more info just say so, I wasn't really sure what all I should include.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do Ajax, however one of the easier ways is to use jQuery.

I dont see any way of replacing all markers using the gmaps4rails gem that it looks like you are using, so you might want to do something with the data before you add it to the map, so that you do not get duplicates.
([Here is another answer where someone have a solution for replacing the markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677039/5010370))

This is an example of how you can use jQuery to do a get request for a new set of markers, whenever someone clicks a button.

```
function updateMarkers() {
    $.get( "my/path/for/map/data/markers", function( data ) {
        // Make sure you have access to the handler variable.
        markers = handler.addMarkers(data);
    });
}
$( "button#with-id-or-something" ).click(updateMarkers);
```

Then in your controller you can render JSON like this:

```
def your_controller_for_ajax_response
    @markers_hash = { ... }
    render json: @markers_hash
end
```