# gmaps4rails callback not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

```
    = gmaps(markers: { data: @json, options: @marker_options }, map_options: @map_options )

    - content_for :map_scripts do
      :javascript
        Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
          alert('asdf') // <-- I never see this alert
        }
```

Using the gmaps4rails gem (v1.5.2), I placed the code above in my view.  My map appears fine with my markers. But with my javascript, shouldn't I get an alert (I'm not)?  I'm not sure if I understand the callback completely.

FYI, the javascript appears fine in my source.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `content_for :scripts` as mentioned in the doc

Plus depending on your browser, you'd better have: `alert('asdf');` instead of `alert('asdf')`

Comment: Tahnks for your response, but I was referring to the alert inside the callback function.  I never see that one.  Shouldn't that callback function be triggered at that point?

Comment: did you change to: content_for :scripts ?

Comment: Yes, I actually got it to work either way.  The problem was I had another callback defined globally.  So I had to remove that and place in each view where needed to avoid conflict.